# Propensity-Score Matching - what's the best choice when matching?

Tags: bias, propensity-scores, matching, weights

I'm using `matchit` package to create a propensity match.
I'm trying to match control and treated with a 2:1 ratio in order to maximize the population and exclude less patients as possible (13.000 patients available).
I have found two possible ways and I am wondering which one is better:

1. method=nearest, ratio 2:1, min.control=1 and max.control=3. In this way I obtain a good matched population with precise 2:1 ratio and good sample size (almost 12.000 patients)
2. method=nearest, caliper = 0.1 and a ratio of 3:1. In this way I still obtain a good match but a not completely balanced population.
   Are the two ways good options that avoid risk of bias or one of the 2 is superior to the other one?